# TextWatcher in fragment

Tags: java, android, macos

I've got this java file:

```html
package com.example.tabbedapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    protected TextView ulamekLabel;
    protected EditText licznik;
    protected EditText mianownik;
    protected TextView kUlamkowa;
    protected TextView calosci;
    protected TextView nLicznik;
    protected TextView nMianownik;
    protected TextView kreska;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        licznik.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                skracamy();
            }
        });

        mianownik.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                skracamy();
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
    }

    private void skracamy() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((CharSequence) licznik) || TextUtils.isEmpty((CharSequence) mianownik)) {
            calosci.setText("0");
            calosci.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nLicznik.setText("0");
            nLicznik.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nMianownik.setText("0");
            nMianownik.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            kreska.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        }

        int a = Integer.parseInt(licznik.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(mianownik.getText().toString());

        int l = (a / NWD(a, b));//.toString().toInt();
        int m = (b / NWD(a, b));//.toString().toInt();

        int c = (l / m);//.toString().toInt();
        int d = (l % m);//.toString().toInt();

        calosci.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nLicznik.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nMianownik.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        kreska.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (c != 0 && d != 0) {
            calosci.setText(c);
            nLicznik.setText(d);
            nMianownik.setText(m);
        } else if (d != 0) {
            calosci.setText("");
            nLicznik.setText(d);
            nMianownik.setText(m);
        } else {
            calosci.setText(c);
            nLicznik.setText("0");
            nMianownik.setText("0");
        }
    }

    int NWD(int a, int b)
    {
        if(b!=0)
            return NWD(b,a%b);
        return a;
    }
}
```

And ofter debug I get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference`. I'm working on a fragment so I can't use findViewById(). Can anyone help? I just need to assign the view to a pointer eg. kreska = findViewById(R.id.kreska) but for fragments. I'm new to java. This file I'm actually translating from Kotlin to java but from main_activity to fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the views but forgot to initialize them.

> all views are uninitialized, that's why showing null object reference

**Declaration**

```java
protected EditText licznik;
protected EditText mianownik;
```

**Initliazation**

```java
licznik = findViewById(R.id.ID1);
mianownik = findViewById(R.id.ID2);
```

**inflate and return view inside `onCreateView`**

```java
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_FRAGMENT, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

**initiate view inside onViewCreated**

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  licznik = view.findViewById(R.id.ID1);
  mianownik = view.findViewById(R.id.ID2);

  ...
}
```

You can face some crashes when initializing the views inside `onCreateView` because sometimes the view is not properly initialized. So always initialize views inside `onViewCreated`.

> Called immediately after onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored into the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.

`onViewCreated` is a make sure that the view is fully created.

Comment: How to do it if I wan't to use eg. licznik outside of onCreateView? In this configuration I can't.

Comment: @Greg just declare it as you're declaring now but you must have to initialize it inside onCreateView()

Comment: `protected EditText licznik` then inside `EditText licznik = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.licznik)` but I can't use it outside onCreateView.

Comment: @Greg check the updates answer